# Why drag and drop is not working in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to drag an element into another element using Selenium WebDriver but it's not working. I tried all the solutions which I can find on internet but none of the solutions seems to be working for me.

```
WebElement sourceelement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("XXX"));
WebElement destelement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("YYY"));
```

Code1:-

```
Actions builder = new Actions( _controls.getDriver());
builder.dragAndDrop(sourceelement, destelement);
```

Code2:-

```
Actions builder = new Actions(_controls.getDriver());
Action dragAndDrop =
builder.clickAndHold(sourceelement).moveToElement(destelement).release(destelement).build();
Thread.sleep(2000);
dragAndDrop.perform()
```

Code3:-

```
Point coordinates1 = sourceelement.getLocation();
Point coordinates2 = destelement.getLocation();  
Robot robot = new Robot();           
robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX(), coordinates1.getY());
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX(), coordinates2.getY());
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Code4:-

```
final String java_script =
"var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
                "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun" +
                "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(for" +
                "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea" +
                "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev" +
                "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);" +
                "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('" +
                "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit(" +
                "'drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";

        ((JavascriptExecutor)_controls.getDriver()).executeScript(java_script, sourceelement, destelement);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

None of the above code is working for me. All the above runs without any error but drag and drop is not happening in the application. Anyone having any other solution ? Thanks.

Browser :- IE

Comment: `dragAndDrop` function does't work with java 1.8 or later.

Comment: Really ? Never heard about this issue in the internet. Also, I am able to drag and drop on the different site. Facing issue with this specific site.

Comment: Naseem, can you add exact error you are facing?

Comment: @NarendraC ... Code is running without any error but drag and drop is not happening in the application

Comment: :) That means we are yet to reach to correct step or method, isn't it?

Comment: me also try all above code but they are not correct.

Comment: String fromLink = "//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a";
    String tolink = "lst-ib";
    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath(fromLink));
    Thread.sleep(500);
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id(tolink));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();

Comment: By this code it will drag upto the given location but not drop it on that location,so anyone kind me sujjest, how i drop in given location..in IE

Answer (score 4):

**I have used the following solution (only tested with Chrome, but should be compatible with IE):**

The javascript was borrowed from: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/javascript-execution-selenium

Save the following javascript in a file somewhere in your solution - it makes reuse easier.

```
function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {},
        setData: function (key, value) {
            this.data[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return this.data[key];
        }
    };
    return event;
}
function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) {
    if (transferData !== undefined) {
        event.dataTransfer = transferData;
    }
    if (element.dispatchEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.type, event);
    }
}
function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) {
    var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);
    var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');
    dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);
    var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer);
}
```

I have used the following code to read in the javascript and execute the drag and drop.

```
protected void JavascriptDragAndDrop(IWebElement source, IWebElement target)
{
    string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("<Path To Javascript File>");
    script += "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1])";
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript(script, source, target);
}
```

This is C# code, and it looks like you are working with Java, but it should be easy enough to translate. Just read the javascript file into a string, concatenate the line that actually calls the javascript function, and use a JavaScriptExecutor to execute the script.

*The linked guide also provides an example of a wrapper method written in Java.*

I've tried most of the methods you listed in the question, and this has been the only solution I found that is both reliable and concise.

Comment: Can't try this out right now, but upvote nonetheless. Looking forward to the day I'll be needing this! The Selenium dragAndDrop has never worked except on canvas elements, which is not really applicable in a business environment.

Comment: This worked smoothly.

Comment: I tried this on [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-drag-and-drop/) but it did not work. I got following error: `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage is not a function`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Worked Perfectly for me :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.simulateDragDrop = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new $.simulateDragDrop(this, options);
        });
    };
    $.simulateDragDrop = function(elem, options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.simulateEvent(elem, options);
    };
    $.extend($.simulateDragDrop.prototype, {
        simulateEvent: function(elem, options) {
            /*Simulating drag start*/
            var type = "dragstart";
            var event = this.createEvent(type);
            this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, event);

```
       type = 'dragover';
       var dragOverEvent2 = this.createEvent(type, {pageX: 200, pageY: 300});
        var $dragOverTarget2 = $(options.dropTarget);
        this.dispatchEvent($dragOverTarget2[0], type, dragOverEvent2);

        /*Simulating drop*/
        type = "drop";
        var dropEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
        dropEvent.offsetX =800;
        dropEvent.offsetY =500;
        dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
        var target;
        if (options.dropTargetFrame) {
            target = $(document.querySelector(options.dropTargetFrame).contentDocument.querySelector(options.dropTarget))[0];
        }
        else {
            target = $(options.dropTarget)[0];
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(target, type, dropEvent);

        /*Simulating drag end*/
        type = "dragend";
        var dragEndEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
        dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
        this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, dragEndEvent);
    },
    createEvent: function(type) {
        var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            types: [],
            setData: function(type, val){
                this.types.push(type)
                this.data[type] = val;
            },
            getData: function(type){
                return this.data[type];
            }
        };
        return event;
    },
    dispatchEvent: function(elem, type, event) {
        if(elem.dispatchEvent) {
            elem.dispatchEvent(event);
        }else if( elem.fireEvent ) {
            elem.fireEvent("on"+type, event);
        }
    }
});
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: This solution worked for drag and drop web element to canvas